# IntelliJ - Git is not installed: Cannot identify version of git executable: no response

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ on my MacBook and get this message every time I open the app. I already checked the Preferences > Version Control > Git under "Path to Git executable" and set this path to the path that is shown in my terminal for `whereis git`. Also, testing the path in the IntelliJ settings returns a "Git version is 2.30.1". What else can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Would it be an option for you to use Homebrew git? Could you please install it and change bath to brew Git in IDE settings?  There is a chance that you have faced known issue with xcode Git: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248193

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov Yes I'm using Homebrew git instead of git in IntelliJ at the moment. The path to brew git is in "whereis git" right? If so, the path in the IDE settings is already set to brew git.

Comment: >The path to brew git is in "whereis git" right?
Not necessarily, you may not have changed your PATH variable and it may store your xCode git there. path to homebrew git `/usr/local/bin/git`

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov If I set the "Path to Git executable" to `/usr/local/bin/git` and test it in the settings, it says "Git is not installed No such file"

Comment: same issue on window, intellij version 2023.2.4

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my case, the IDE seems only be able to recognize the path of `git` as `/usr/local/bin/git`, but `git` is installed at `/usr/bin/git`. So I made a softlink between of them.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you, I think this just solved the problem!

Comment: Yes, its working with my Android Studio , in MAC 
Thanks ...

Comment: In my case, I changed the Path to Git executable under Preferences > Version Control > Git to /usr/bin/git and it worked. Thanks for giving me an idea as to what the problem was.

Comment: This worked for me (MacOS , IntelliJ). thanks.

Answer (score 75):

In my case the issue was solved by invalidating cache and restarting IDE. Simply go to Files -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: That worked temporarily for me but next time I restarted my computer I got the error again.

Comment: You can just restart without invalidating - it will help

Answer (score 6):

Open `Preferences > Git` > version control > git > `Path to Git executables` :
set to

> /usr/local/bin/git

or

> /usr/bin/git

Answer (score 2):

For people using windows with wsl2, IntelliJ might automatically detect the correct file, but sometimes is not able to access. Restarting wsl and IntelliJ helped for me:

1. Restart wsl

- Open cmd as admin
- run "wsl.exe --shutdown"
- run "wsl.exe"

2. Restart intelliJ

Comment: Worked for PyCharm on WSL

Answer (score 1):

All of the methods above are not working for me.

First of all, I Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart.
Secondly, I have to run the git command manually. Then it seems trigger something internally to find git path, I guess. Afterwards it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed this issue by going to Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle and update `Gradle JDK` from `1.8` to `11`

Answer (score 0):

Just update/install git with following command:

> brew install git

Go to Intellij IDEA (Top left corner) -> Preference -> Version control -> Git -> Enter "/usr/local/bin/git" (generally git is installed in this path to verify it once, you can enter the same in finder) for "Path to git executable"

Boom!! Your Git is back.

Cheers!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting `Pycharm` fixed this problem: I did not need to `Invalidate Caches` or fix the `git` executable path.